# Customized Metadata Columns on Marten

Tags: marten

I'm building an application with a complicated security model. For each row, and for the majority of the persisted entities, I have to store several lists of roles, individual user ids, scopes and attributes.

I know that I can use [duplicated fields](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/documents/customizing/duplicated_fields/) to improve performance. But I would rather not store the described data with the entity. My concern is not as much with duplication but with the performance penalty of using JSON and the costs of serialisation/deserialization.

Marten uses [metadata columns](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/schema/metadata/). Can I create my own Metadata Columns to support the security aspects of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Marten's metadata columns are hard-coded in their [source](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/b2a33ea8af0677016bbb31a08897a4079f8af054/src/Marten/Storage/DocumentMetadata.cs).

You could fork Marten and change the DocumentMetadata.cs hard-coded values and calls, or create a solution that lets a user configure these columns.